# How to interate the Json data in PHP and place it in a PHP variable?

Tags: drupal

How do I iterate through the Json object that has an array within it and places the description object in a variable that can be used in another function?

This is the Json scheme that is being pulled in with $regResult:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "401.07.001",
      "description": "Invalid Access Token",
      "link": "https://developer.arity.com/registration-services/apis"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The variable is named `$item->description` for each error.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options

- just use `return $registration_result;` and pass it to the other function as  a parameter
- Declare your variable as global `global $registration_result = drupal_json_decode($regResult);`
- Save the value to the database

Comment: I only need the description object.